# opencart Need to show option quantity in admin panel per product in

Tags: php, opencart

I really need this as most of my products have options in Opencart. I need to show option quantities for each product in the admin list.

At the moment in the quantity column it just shows a number. It would be better if it said for example Strawberry: 12 Vanilla: 5.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is see if there is an extension for this on the OpenCart extension page. If there is no extension then this is what you will need to do. 1) Find which database table this information is in (I think its product). Then query it in your model , pass it to your controller, and then echo that variable/ array in your view. I will provide you roughly with the code you will need, however you need to tweak it to do what you want.
    This should go in the appropriate Model file:

```
public function getProductName() {
     $query = $this->database->query("SELECT * product_name FROM product"); /*this gets all the info you want, however I am not %100 on the names, so double check your database*/
if (isset($query){ /*says if array is not NULL and is set*/
return getProductName(); /* return the function */ 
}
else {$query = ""} /*else the array is NULL*/
{
```

This should go in your Controller:

```
$this->load->model('path/to/model/file') /*however you might not need this depending on which model file you place your query (model code)*/
$this->data['productName'] = $this->path_to_model->getProductName(); /*this passes it to your view file as the array productName*/
```

This should go in your View:

You will see certain HTML tags and foreach loops on your view page, you will want to basically copy the view code for displaying the array properly, however it should look something like this:

```
 <tr>
 <td>
      <?php foreach ($productName->rows as $tempVariable) { /*this is roughly how you will get each product name from database table to print on a page, obviously if you want to display it next to its quantity you will need to change it around by using HTML and PHP code in conjugation, however I hope this has helped*/
            echo $tempVariable; ?>
 </td>
 </tr>
```